# when deployed Spring Boot war in tomcat where should application.yml file should be placed?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot

When spring boot,mvc war file has been deployed in stand alone tomcat, `application.yml` is located at `$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/demo/WEB-INF/classes/application.yml`

Can I move the same to `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost/dmo.yml` ?

In general without using spring boot my configuration file will be located at  `$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/demo/META-INF/context.xml` which can be moved to `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost/demo.xml`

Is the same is possible for `application.yml` also? Then How?

This will help while re-deploying my config file will be backed-up automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the default location for `application.properties/yml` files using `spring.config.location` and `spring.config.name` properties and their corresponding environment variables. The easiest way is to set the `SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION` environment variable:

```
export SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION=$CATALINA_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost/dmo.yml
```

Check out spring boot documentation for more info on [loading property files](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files).

Comment: How spring.config.location value will be set? Suppose if I fixed the location to $CATALINA_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost/ which will be like hard coding the config location right?

Comment: If I change my tomcat setenv.sh file with the below JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS --spring.config.location=classpath:/application.yml is it fine?

Comment: Setting the environment variable is the easiest way to do that

Comment: if I want to add one more application config export SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION=$CATALINA_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost/demo.yml:$CATALINA_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost/demo1.yml is it fine?